# Logging search queries for logged-in users

Tags: wp-query, users, search, logging

How would it be possible, to create a log file and update it with the search queries of users, who are logged in?

I'd probably use fopen() and fwrite() php functions for saving the log files, but first I'd need a way to 'catch' the data I need.
Checking if a user is logged in is easy, as well as getting the user name, but how would I get the search query variables every time a user uses the search function?

Thanks in advance, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `get_search_query();` function.
More in [developer.wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_query/)

Comment: Thanks, that will surely work if the search field is filled. What if the user runs a category/taxonomy search and leaves the search field empty?

Comment: What do you mean by the category/taxonomy search?

Comment: Most sites call it advanced search, or refined search, when the user is able to filter results based on category or other post data (e.g. price, color, size in a webshop). I'd also like to be able to log those search attributes.

Comment: @galingong then you should do it in the action function that this form sends the data for filtering.